# Brezis' exercise 8.25.5: is $u \in W^{2, \infty}(I)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $I$ be the open interval $(0, 2)$. Consider the bilinear form on $H^1 (I)$
$$
a(u, v) = \int_0^2 u'v' + \left(\int_0^1 u\right) \left(\int_0^1 v\right) .
$$

I'm trying to solve a problem in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> **Exercise 8.25**
>
> 1. Check that $a(u, v)$ is a continuous symmetric bilinear form, and that $a(u, u)=0$ implies $u=0$.
> 2. Prove that $a$ is [coercive](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Lax%E2%80%93Milgram_theorem#The_Lax%E2%80%93Milgram_theorem).
> 3. Deduce that for every $f \in L^2(I)$ there exists a unique $u \in H^1(I)$ satisfying
>    $$
>    (1) \quad
>    a(u, v)=\int_0^2 f v
>    \quad \forall v \in H^1(I) .
>    $$
>    What is the corresponding minimization problem?
> 4. Show that the solution of (1) belongs to $H^2(I)$ and in particular $u \in C^1(\bar{I})$. Determine the equation and the boundary conditions satisfied by $u$.
> 5. Assume that $f \in C(\bar{I})$, and let $u$ be the solution of (1). Prove that $u$ belongs to $W^{2, p}(I)$ for every $p<\infty$. Show that $u \in C^2(\bar{I})$ iff $\int_I f=0$.

In below attempt of (5.), I get $u \in W^{2, p}(I)$ even when $p = \infty$. Could you confirm if I made any subtle mistakes?

---

Clearly, $u \in H^2(I)$ implies $u \in C^1(\bar{I})$. Because $I$ is bounded, we get $u \in W^{1, p}(I)$ for any $p \in [1, \infty]$. Let $g (x) := (\int_0^1 u) 1_{(0, 1)} (x)$ for $x \in I$. From $(1)$, we get
$$
(2) \quad
\int_I [u'v' + gv] = \int_I f v
\quad \forall v \in H^1(I).
$$

By integration by parts, $u \in H^2(I)$ with $u'' = g-f$ and $u'(0)=u'(2)=0$. It follows from $f \in C(\bar{I})$ that $f$ is bounded. Clearly, $g$ is bounded, so $u''$ is bounded and thus $u \in W^{2, p}(I)$ for any $p \in [1, \infty]$.

We consider $u \in C^2(\bar{I})$. Then $u''$ is continuous. This implies $g$ is continuous and thus $g=\int_0^1 u=0$. We substitute $v=1$ into $(2)$ and get $\int_I f =0$.

We consider $\int_I f =0$. We substitute $v=1$ into $(2)$ and get $\int_I g =0$ and thus $g=0$. This implies $u''=-f \in C(\bar{I})$.